# DomXpath doesn't get the img tag

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm trying to get the src attribute's value from a img tag. The problem is that domxpath doesn't reach the tag at all. I've don var_dump on the query result, and it says:

> object(DOMNodeList)#51 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }

I've also tried to get the attribute through:
`$xpath->query('/a[1]/div/img/@src')`
and 
`$xpath->query('/a[1]/div/img/')[0]->getAttribute('src')`
however, the problem is that xpath doesn't get neither the node... (with $xpath->query('/a[1]/div/'), works)

```
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $articles = $xpath->query('//*[@id="root"]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[3]/article/div[@data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image"]');
    var_dump($articles[0]->getAttribute('class'));
    echo "<br /><br />";

    foreach($articles as $key => $article){
        $title = $xpath->query('div/a[2]/h1', $article)[0]->nodeValue;
        $par = $xpath->query('a[2]/div/p/text()', $article)[0]->nodeValue;
        $img = $xpath->query('a[1]/div/img/@src', $article);
        var_dump($img);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` succeed ? Try to display `$dom->saveHTML()` to see what is really loaded.

Comment: Yes of course. The queries which gets the titles ($title = ecc.) and the paragraphs ($par = ecc.) work. But when I try to get the image tag (with the query $xpath->query('a[1]/div/img'); ) and I execute var_dump on the result, it says object(DOMNodeList)#51 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }...

$dom->saveHTML() returns the page content i want to scrape

Comment: In this case difficult to say what is wrong without the document.

Comment: the document i want to scrape (at the moment, i'm doing only tests) is https://www.apnews.com/. The part of the html code i'm working on is (using the XPath : //*[@id="root"]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[3]/article/div[@data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image"]).
As I've said, the code works with $title and $par, but it doesn't with the tag img.

Comment: You can also have a look at the html code i'm working on at https://tlgur.com/d/GJN6yE2G

Comment: You can't access to img tags because they don't exist at the time the document is send by the server (what you get with `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`). They are dynamically created by Javascript (probably from the enormous json data at the end of the file).